# filter rows based on their Sum in dplyR R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidy

I am trying to get things right using the dplyr package in R.
Imagine that I have the iris dataset, which looks like this

```
library(tidyverse)
iris=iris[,1:4]
head(iris)

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
```

**I want to keep only the rows whose sum is bigger or equal (>=) 10**. With baseR i can do it
like this

```
iris[rowSums(iris) >= 10, , drop = FALSE]
```

How could do I do this using dplyR and the `rowSums function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)

iris1=iris[,1:4]
iris1 %>% filter(rowSums(.) >= 10)
```